# Chamfer Matching error in python opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I've been trying out various algorithms for my thesis. And now i'm currently focusing in template matching (where the main focus in matching would be the edge). Then I found out about chamfer matching. I'm torn between coding it myself, or using available implementations (which is better). Then I found out about a cpp implementation of the said algorithm. However, I'm encountering weird error. ↓

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (img.type() == CV_8UC1 && templ.type() == CV_8UC1)
in chamerMatching, file /home/pyimagesearch/Downloads/opencv-2.4.8/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp, line 1370
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "template.py", line 12, in <module> cv2.chamerMatching(template1, queryFrame, 1, 1) cv2.error: 
/home/pyimagesearch/Downloads/opencv-2.4.8/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp:1370: 
error: (-215) img.type() == CV_8UC1 && templ.type() == CV_8UC1 in function chamerMatching
```

i tried to locate the directory /home/pyimagesearch/Downloads/opencv-2.4.8/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp (so as to inspect whether i'm missing out on the parameter required for the function call), but to my surprise, there's no opencv-2.4.8 folder under my Downloads folder.

does anyone know what could be the main cause of the error? 
Your answer would be much appreciated. :) thanks!

Comment: i think i already found the file, its in /usr/local/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp... thanks all! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think type function don't return value like cv8uc1 . It should return integer value. You can find list of integer value map which is returned by type function in following page http://ninghang.blogspot.com.tr/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html?m=1. Could you change them and try again ?